# Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: FIRAuth

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, xamarin.ios, sdk

I have created a xamarin iOS app by binding the native objective c library.
Until now everything worked fine the xamarin ios app also worked fine. Now I have added Firebase frameworks (Firebase Auth, Database, Analytics, InstanceID) in my native objective c library to use firebase and created the binding the same way I used to do before with xamarin iOS. However, I am facing the below error in xamarin iOS app.

The errors below:

> *Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: FIRAuth. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAuth' could not be found in any
>   of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application. (MT5211)*
>
> *Error MT5211: Native linking failed, undefined Objective-C class: FIRDatabase. The symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRDatabase' could not be found
>   in any of the libraries or frameworks linked with your application.*

I have tried things like :

1. Added the Firebase NuGet packages inside the App.
2. Specify the frameworks in the [LinkWith] attribute.
3. Do the below thing specified in the xamarin errors documentation:

   A third-party binding bound an Objective-C protocol but did not annotate it with the [Protocol] attribute in its API definition. However, I don't know exactly where to add it.

   I have added it to the ApiDefiniton that I have created, but it didn't help.

It's been a while I am trying to solve the error however couldn't do that.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/16489/new-type-registrar-in-xamarin-ios-7-2-1-errors-mt5210-and-mt5211#latest

Comment: Hi. Did you find way to fix it?

Comment: @DmitryZinoviev I have used refections in native objective c frameworks so that the frameworks will use firebase at runtime.